# What type of beetle is this? It was on the wall in my backyard

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This insect was on the wall in my backyard. I live in Southern California. Does anyone know what is is?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. We would need at least 1 picture, preferably high quality and close-up of the insect/beetle in question to identify.

Answer (score 1):

The wide, flat body makes me think that's a roach, not a beetle. Beetles normally have an exoskeleton over their wings, not exposed wings. Based on the pic you provided and these two websites, I think it's a German cockroach, *Blatella germanica*

https://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/B/I-OT-BGER-CO.004.html

https://www.corkyspest.com/cockroach-id.html